# Update column according to row number using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
ID          Group
----------- ----------- 
2           NULL
4           NULL
7           NULL
8           NULL
11          NULL
12          NULL
```

I want to update my table according to row number like this

```
ID          Group
----------- ----------- 
2           G_1
4           G_1
7           G_2
8           G_2
11          G_3
12          G_3
```

First N rows    ---> G_1,

N+1 to 2N rows  ---> G_2,

2N+1 to 3N rows ---> G_3.

...

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kenny, check my edits.  Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: What version of SQl Server?  finding a "row number" is a lot easier in SQL 2005 onward.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using SQL 2005 or later:

```
DECLARE @n integer
SELECT @N = 3;

WITH rows AS
(
  SELECT
     ID, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RowNum   
  FROM temp
)
UPDATE temp
SET [Group] = 'G_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),((RowNum-1) / @N) + 1)
FROM temp
INNER JOIN rows ON temp.ID = rows.ID
```

Comment: concat is sqlserver 2012+

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thanks - changed back to string concatenation.

Comment: the join is a waste though. Check my answer

Comment: I was just building up a windowing method when you posted yours, very nice.  As OP doesnt look like he's being very active, i'll hand out a few upvotes. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @n INT
SET @n = 5

UPDATE my_table
SET [Group] = 'G_' + CAST((row_nums.row_num / (@n + 1)) + 1 AS VARCHAR) 
FROM
(SELECT 
    my_table.ID,
    my_table.[Group],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY my_table.ID) row_num
From my_table 
) row_nums
WHERE row_nums.ID = my_table.ID
```

Comment: The partitioning seems to be the way to go on this answer. +1.  Looping is valid too tho. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @N int = 2

declare @t table(ID int, Grp char(3))

insert @t(id) values(2),(4),(7),(8),(11),(12)

;with x as
(
  select id, Grp,
  (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ID)+1) / @N rn
  from @t
)
update x 
set grp = 'G_' + cast(rn as varchar(9))

select * from @t
```

Result:

```
ID  Grp
2   G_1
4   G_1
7   G_2
8   G_2
11  G_3
12  G_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why update at all? It's kind of poor form to store calculated values. What happens if your ID would have to change in the future? (It really shouldn't if it's the primary key, but I live in the real world where real life happens.)

```
SELECT id,
    CASE 
        WHEN id <= n and id > 2*n then 'G_' + '1'
        WHEN id <= 2*n and id > 3*n then 'G_' + '2'
        WHEN id < 3*n then 'G_' + '3'
    END AS GROUP
```

Depending on your purpose, you could put this into a view, or a calculated column.

Comment: The group is based on the _row number_, not the `ID`.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that @DStanley.